# Rapids CUML Random Forest Regression Model Inference

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, machine-learning-model, rapids

I am using the Random Forest Regression model from CUML 0.10.0 library on Google Colab and having trouble with obtaining model predictions. After the model training ends successfully, I am using the (.predict) method for inference on a very large array of size (41697600, 11). However, I am receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: GPU predict model only accepts float32 dtype as input, convert the data to float32 or use the CPU predict with `predict_model='CPU'`.
```

The error persists even after casting the input numpy array's dtype to float32 and specifying the predict_model='CPU' argument in the predict method.

This is the used code for your reference:

```
array=(X_test.values).astype('float32')
predictions = cuml_model.predict(array, predict_model='CPU',output_class=False, algo='BATCH_TREE_REORG')
```

Model summary:

```
<bound method RandomForestRegressor.print_summary of RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10, max_depth=16, handle=<cuml.common.handle.Handle object at 0x7fbfa342e888>, max_features='auto', n_bins=8, n_streams=8, split_algo=1, split_criterion=2, bootstrap=True, bootstrap_features=False, verbose=False, min_rows_per_node=2, rows_sample=1.0, max_leaves=-1, accuracy_metric='mse', quantile_per_tree=False, seed=-1)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is extremely confusing. I believe it's failing because the *training* was in float64 not the prediction. So if you train in float32 instead, this should all work. The optimized GPU implementation of prediction only supports float32 *models* at this time. You should be able to fall back to the slow CPU prediction, but this exception is blocking it.

I filed this as a bug and we'll try to get a fix in for the upcoming release. Feel free to follow along there or add any extra questions etc.: https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml/issues/1406

Comment: Thank you so much. Indeed, this was the case. The problem was resolved after retraining using float32 arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error for `int64` but the error was showing for `float64`. So, anyone having the same issue can simply convert `int64` to `float32` or `int32`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30224438)

Comment: It kinda does. If anyone face the same error but can't resolve it because the wrong message is being shown. So my solution should solve this issue.